# How to customize(have multiple images) in feed post dialog

Tags: facebook, customization

I've seen an example where feed post had multiple images. How can I make the same thing? There is only parameter for the image in API.
[Customized feed post](http://www.powerreviews.com/assets/images/facebook2.png)

Comment: I found solution. I generate 1 image containing all images I need on server side. Not elegant, but I guess it's better than using deprecated API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still call old api calls with oauth and Graph API-like calls

All you have to do is make the request to: https://api.facebook.com/method/stream.publish?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN&_arguments_for_stream_publish_

Here is the documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/

You just have to put more than 1 image as attachment

Answer (score 2):

it was possible a while ago via some of the old api, but it is now deprecated

Comment: I wonder why FB decided to cut the functionality... So now only 1 image are allowed?

Comment: yep, only 1 image per feed story